The high-side of gate driver (2EDR8259HXUMA) is not producing the PWM output signal
Over the past week, I've encountered an issue where one of my gate drivers isn't generating outputs while the remaining two are generating the desired outputs. I'm using 2EDR8259HXUMA gate drivers for N-Channel MOSFETs. There are two isolated output ports (OUTA and OUTB) in each gate driver. In my situation, one of the gate drivers is only generating output from the OUTA port, and in the OUTB port, the output is zero. I set the input voltage to the gate driver (VDDI) to be 12V DC and checked that the pins were not shorted. I've attached the application diagram for the gate driver.
What would be the possible reasons for getting the output at one port but not at another port of the same gate driver? 

Has it ever worked or, is it a new design?

Is it a power supply necessary at VDDB/GNDB?

It is a new design, and a power supply is necessary at VDDB.
